# If in list function - python

Tags: python, list, function, if-statement

I am having an issue with writing functions to determine if firstly, something is in a list and secondly, in relation to the user having a bank balance.

Essentially what the function needs to do is, allow the user to use their balance to bet on a team and also check if the team they have typed in is in the list of teams.

This is what I have so far if anybody could help me with this. I feel like it may need to be one function for both but can't work it out and other threads have not helped me, thanks.

```
team_list = ["Team1", "Team2", "Team3"]

def Team():
    team = input("Please choose a team to bet on.")
    if team in team_list:
        print("You have selected",team)
    else:
        print("That team is not in the list please select one in the list")
        return Team()

def Stake():
    bank = float(50.0)
    stake = float(input("Please enter a stake"))
    if stake <= bank:
        print("Your bet has been placed.", stake, "on", team)
        bank -= stake
        print(bank)
    else:
        print("You don't have enough money to place this")
        return Stake()

Team()
Stake()
```

Comment: You need to actually return the `team` value then use it later.

Comment: Thank you how would i do that just by calling it at the start of the stake function with 'Team()'?

Comment: It looks like you're mixing two things:  You're treating `team` and `stake` as globals (but have not declared them as such, so it's not working), and you're also trying to return them (but only when recursing, so again it doesn't work).  If you want them to be global, then declare them `global` inside the functions.

Answer (score 1):

You need to learn more about variable scope.
The `team` variable is a local variable to the `Team` function, that means `team` only exists within the scope defined by `Team`. That means that in `Stake` there is no variable called `team`.

To deal with this you need to pass some variables around using return statements and parameters. First you need to return the `team` variable from `Team`:

```
def Team():
    team = input("Please choose a team to bet on.")
    if team in team_list:
        return team
```

Then you can use this later, by first storing that return value then passing it as a parameter to `Stake`:

```
selected_team = Team()
print("You have selected", selected_team)
Stake(selected_team)
```

Where `Stake` is modified so it can take a parameter:

```
def Stake(team):
    #now team variable *is* accessible through the parameter
```

Answer (score 1):

The scope of `team` variable used is `Team` is limited to itself.
It cannot be accessed in the `Stake` function. 
In order to resolve the problem, here is what you can do:

```
team_list = ["Team1", "Team2", "Team3"]
bank = 50.0

def Team():
   team = input("Please choose a team to bet on.")
   if team in team_list:
       print("You have selected",team)
       Stake(team)
   else:
       print("That team is not in the list please select one in the list")
       return Team()

def Stake(team):
    bank = float(50.0)
    stake = float(input("Please enter a stake"))
    if stake <= bank:
        print("Your bet has been placed.", stake, "on", team)
        bank -= stake
        print(bank)
    else:
        print("You don't have enough money to place this")
        return Stake(team)
Team()
```

Moreover,if you want to merge these two functions, you might have to work a bit. However, first - you should understand about `variable scoping`.
Check the official documentation: [variable scoping](https://docs.python.org/3.3/index.html).
It might be old but it still is relevant.